# What is the difference between FIware Cosmos and Apache Spark?

Tags: fiware, filab

What is the difference between FIware Cosmos and Apache Spark ?

Answer (score 2):

as I told you by email Cosmos is not a new Big Data system but a manager of Hadoop clusters; it allows for cluster creation on demand on top of FIWARE infrastructure, among other management services. It is quite similar to Openstack Sahara... in fact, we are thinking to move to Sahara in the medium time. Sahara is quite interesting because it allows the deployment of Spark clusters as well.

So, maybe in a few months you can use our platform in order to ask for a Spark cluster.